# Angular elements web component creating memory leak

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-elements

I created two pages first one is listing & the second one is details page with `mat-tabs`. One of the tab contains web component(ViewComponent) created using angular/elements.

Following is the html for the details page.

```html
<mat-tab-group>
<-- other tabs -->

    <mat-tab *ngIf="tabName === viewComp">
      <ng-template mat-tab-label>
        <span>{{ label }}</span>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-container
        *ngIf="loadedTabs.viewComp && apiSuccess"
      >
        <div *ngIf="testCondition">
          <-- ViewComponent is web component created using angular/elements -->
          <view-component
            [data]="viewCompData"
          ></view-component>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Now if I go back to listing page from details. ViewComponent still persist in memory following is screenshot of memory snapshot after garbage collection.

[image]

Now if I remove the `div` element with `testCondition` then in the retainers window its showing `nameSpacesByHostElement` instead of `collectedLeaveElements`.

[image]

Clicking on the top `__ngContext__ in Detached HTMLElement@236587` jumps to following source - constructor of `NgElementImpl`.

[image]

Please let me know how can I remove ViewComponent permanently from memory.
Using Angular(v10.2) / material components(v10.2).

Comment: Can you try upgrading to a more recent version of angular. Have a look into https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/45080 as it might be related. It's indicating that there are ongoing revisions to Angular to surface in v14 and that some memory leak cause by Chrome is going to be fixed by v102 being released soon.